# How to add needle to gauge?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a d3 v4 gauge and whilst I have the gauge background colors set, I cannot get the needle to display, even if I hard code the value for it.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/K9XdtwN2yhiTezuOwVpe?p=preview

```
needle.data( 33 )
    .transition()
    .ease( d3.easeElasticOut )
    .duration( 2000 )
    .attr( "transform", function( d ) {
    // r = 180 * d / data[ 1 ]
       r = 33;
       return " translate(200,200) rotate(" + r + ")"
    });
```

Comment: your question is little closer to myn would you mind checking this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966889/adding-min-and-max-values-to-gauge-chart-in-d3-v4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
var needle = svg.selectAll( ".needle" )
    .data( 0 )
```

it should be:

```
var needle = svg.selectAll( ".needle" )
    .data( [0] ) //should be in array
```

Next when you create the needle  you must give it a class like this:

```
var needle = svg.selectAll( ".needle" )
    .data( [0] )
    .enter()
    .append( 'line' )
    .attr( "x1", 0 )
    .attr( "x2", -78 )
    .attr( "y1", 0 )
    .attr( "y2", 0 )
    .classed("needle", true)//give it a class
```

So that you can give transition like this:

```
    svg.selectAll( ".needle" ).data( [103] )
        .transition()
        .ease( d3.easeElasticOut )
        .duration( 2000 )
        .attr( "transform", function( d ) {
            return "translate(200,200) rotate(" + d + ")"
        });
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ij9BaSVeyArsqfcCCr0G?p=preview)

Comment: I want to use this chart in my application, trying to understand the chart,like showing the needle between min and max values. for example i want to show needle at 60 where min is 40 and max is 90. could you please point me where i can change it, i tried changing current and previous values including data, doesn't work.

Comment: Make an SO question with minimum verifiable code. I am surely you get help