# Adding min and max values to gauge chart in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, d3.js

I am new to d3 v4, want to build a gauge chart where i can give min, max and actual needle value, lets say i want the needle to be shown at 60 with min as 50 and max as 80 instead of 0 to 100, thanks for [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156586/how-to-add-needle-to-gauge/41157311?noredirect=1#comment80836859_41157311) SO question where almost my requirement met except with min and max values. I've tried changing current and previous values including data, doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated. my plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/xKYMlnwh68F0tCxhI1oT?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the plunker.

Link: https://plnkr.co/edit/xa2d3YTxnxU5kBIOenLR?p=preview

By default, the range value is 0, 180 degrees. So to add custom range you need to create a linear scale and pass the values to the scale.
Since your domain is 50, 80 this is how the scale would look like.

`var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([50, 80]).range([0,180]);`

And your update function would look like this

```
svg.selectAll( ".needle" ).data( [60] )
    .transition()
    .ease( d3.easeElasticOut )
    .duration( 2000 )
    .attr( "transform", function( d ) {
      console.log(d, scale(d));
        return "translate(200,200) rotate(" + scale(d) + ")"
    });
```